# Reversing a string word by word

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that reverses a string inputted by the user.

`Enter a sentence: you can cage a swallow can't you
Reversal of sentence: you can't swallow a cage can you`

So I thought about scanning for the string character by character. Then copying the string from the end to the beginning into a new string. At this point, I know that I've got a new word every time I see a space, so I have to invert the order of the letters that are between two spaces. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char sentence[64], reversal[64], reversal_copy[64];
  int i = 0, index = 0;

  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  while(sentence[strlen(sentence)-1]!= '\n'){
    scanf("%c", &sentence[i]);
    i++;
  }
  printf("Reversal of sencente: ");
  for(int h = strlen(sentence) - 2, k = 0; h >= 0; h++, k++){
    reversal[k] = sentence[h];
    strcpy(reversal_copy, reversal);
    if(sentence[h] == ' '){
      for(int m = h; m >= index && m <= h; m--, index++){
        reversal[m] = reversal_copy[index];
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Reversal of sentence: %s\n\n", reversal);

  return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault error and I believe it happens around here:

```
for(int h = strlen(sentence) - 2, k = 0; h >= 0; h++, k++){
        reversal[k] = sentence[h];
```

but I don't quite get why. Could you help me with this?

Comment: You know that SO code formatting doesn't have line numbering, right foxyIT? :)

Comment: @gsamaras sorry edited ahah

Comment: It's ok. In the first while loop use check an **uninitialized array**, which invokes Undefined Behavior...

Comment: Please do not change your question significantly after comments/answers had been give as doing so might render the latter ununderstandable. Add changes as additions. I rolled back your last change though.

Comment: @gsamaras thanks fixed it but the error doesn't seem to be there

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for your first loop to continue is `h >= 0`, and as you are incrementing `h` each time this is going to keep getting bigger until it exceeds the size of `sentence` and throws the error.

If your intention for that loop is to work backwards through `sentence` then I think you should decrement h and k (`h--, k--`), but if the intention is to work forwards through `sentence` then your condition needs to be changed so that the loop finishes once `h` has reached the end of `sentence`

Comment: In general though, a simpler way of solving this problem would be to create an array by splitting `sentence` by ` ` and then performing a reverse loop through the array to rebuild the string

Comment: thanks a lot, I must have checked the code so many times but I totally didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

The word order can be reversed using a recursive function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse ( char *str, char *original) {
    char temp[strlen ( str) + 1];
    temp[0] = 0;
    int offset = 0;

    if ( 1 == sscanf ( str, "%s%n", temp, &offset)) {
        reverse ( str + offset, original);//recursive call
    }
    else {//at the end of the original string
        *original = 0;//set zero at first character
        return;
    }
    //as recursion unwinds, concatenate the words
    strcat ( original, temp);
    if ( str != original) {//will be false when unwinds reaches first iteration
        strcat ( original, " ");
    }
    return;
}

int main( void) {
    char text[] = "you can cage a swallow can't you";

    printf ( "%s\n", text);
    reverse ( text, text);
    printf ( "%s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

During the `while`-loop's 1st iteration `strlen()` is called on an un-initialised variable. This invokes undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

---

In any case of updating a `char`-array character by character you completely ignore the fact that a `0`-terminator is necessary to make a `char`-array a C-string. Only a C-string may be passed to (most of the) `str*()` functions.

---

Also `scanf()` might fail. Test for this.

Comment: You're right thanks, fixed it but the error doesn't seem to be there

Comment: @gsamaras: My answer might not address all issues, right. But definitely one.

Comment: .. or two, or three.